# Configuring Minio Testcontainers with different default port

Tags: spring, docker, minio, testcontainers

**Quick summary: How can I change the default port of the minio client running in my test container?**

I want to use minio as a testcontainer in my application which already working when I start it locally. here is the codesnippet I use to run the testcontainer:

```
public class MinioContainer extends GenericContainer<MinioContainer> {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 9000;
    private static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE = "/minio/minio";
    private static final String DEFAULT_TAG = "latest";

    private static final String MINIO_ACCESS_KEY = "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY";
    private static final String MINIO_SECRET_KEY = "MINIO_SECRET_KEY";

    private static final String DEFAULT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY = "/data";
    private static final String HEALTH_ENDPOINT = "/minio/health/ready";

    public MinioContainer() {

        this(DEFAULT_IMAGE + ":" + DEFAULT_TAG);
    }

    public MinioContainer(String image) {

        super(image == null ? DEFAULT_IMAGE + ":" + DEFAULT_TAG : image);
        Network network = Network.newNetwork();
        withNetwork(network);
        withNetworkAliases("minio-" + Base58.randomString(6));
        addExposedPort(DEFAULT_PORT);
        withEnv(MINIO_ACCESS_KEY, "access_key");
        withEnv(MINIO_SECRET_KEY, "secret_key");
        withCommand("server", DEFAULT_STORAGE_DIRECTORY);
        setWaitStrategy(new HttpWaitStrategy()
                .forPort(DEFAULT_PORT)
                .forPath(HEALTH_ENDPOINT)
                .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1)));
    }

    public String getHostAddress() {

        return getHost() + ":" + getMappedPort(DEFAULT_PORT);
    }
}
```

As soon as I deploy this on our cluster, where also an minio container is running at port 9000, it shows this error message in the console:

```
io.minio.errors.ErrorResponseException: The Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
    at some.package.MinioTest.setup(MinioTest.java:58)
```

In my test i am running a SpringBootTest using this container and injecting my minio client. I also configured a test application yaml so I can run my test with an active test profile. The error happens on following code snippet:

```
private final String BUCKET = "bucket";
....

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    boolean bucketExists = minioClient.bucketExists(BucketExistsArgs.builder().bucket(BUCKET).build());
...
}
```

Is there a way to change the DEFAULT_PORT on my MinioContainer so it is not the same port as the minio container already running on my cluster? I am not able to get my tests running on our pipeline because of this issue, which is only happening on our cluster.

As soon as I change the DEFAULT_PORT to something different than 9000 on my MinioContainer, the Container stops working because it is not able to find the HEALTH_ENDPOINT and therefor the whole container just stops working.

I hope I explained my problem clear enough. If not please tell me so I can try to explain it clearer. I am already completely frustrated with this issue.

BR
Null

Comment: just to be clear, in order to connect to minio container you need to use the MinioContainer#getHostAddress due to it will return the random port provided by testcontainers. Also, the error message is not related to the port but to the access key. My guess is if you are using localhost:9000 then you are connecting to the minio already running in your cluster instead of the one managed by testcontainers.

Comment: Hi @EddúMeléndez yes you are right, this is related to the fact, that my test case is connecting to the minio running in my cluster. The error message is related to the access key which i provide in my test application yaml which does not met the access key defined in the minio running in my cluster. So my question is: How can I change the default port of the minio client running in my test container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. Minio supports the following command:

`"server /data --address :9100"`

Now I was able to generate my testcontainer now like this:

```
 public static GenericContainer<?> minioContainer = new GenericContainer<>(MINIO_IMAGE)
            .withCommand("server /data --address :9100")
            .withExposedPorts(9100);
```

Now the MinioContainer in my Test runs with Port 9100.

Hopefully I was able to help someone else with this issue.